# ot.js error Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm learning on how to create collaborative code editor using SocketIO, CodeMirror and ot.js

but there is this error that i have no idea how to fix.
**here is my socket server code**

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io')
const ot = require('ot')
const roomList = {}

module.exports = server => {
let str = 'just a test'

const io = socketIO(server)
io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log(`${io.engine.clientsCount} connected clients`)

    socket.on('joinRoom', data => {
        if(!roomList[data.roomId]){
            const socketIOServer = new ot.EditorSocketIOServer(str, [], data.roomId, function() {
                cb(true)
            })
            roomList[data.roomId] = socketIOServer
        }
        roomList[data.roomId].addClient(socket)
        roomList[data.roomId].setName(socket, data.username)

        socket.room = data.roomId,
        socket.join(data.roomId)
    })

    socket.on('newMessage', data => {
        io.to(data.roomId).emit('newMessage', data)
    })

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socket.leave(socket.room)
    })
})
}
```

and here is the error

```
myprojectpath/node_modules/ot/lib/editor-socketio-server.js:33
.emit('doc', {
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the `ot` package, it appears that [it assumes](https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js/blob/e9a3a0e214dd6c001e25515274bae0842a8415f2/lib/server.js#L31-L33) that `socket.join()` returns the socket itself. This was the case up to [`socket.io` 2.x.x](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/2.4.1/lib/socket.js#L257), but was changed in [`socket.io` 3.0.0](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/3.0.0/lib/socket.ts#L245). The `join` function now returns `void` or a `Promise`, depending on the adapter used.

You'll either need to make a fork of the `ot` package and bring it up to date (and perhaps make a pull request), or try downgrading your `socket.io` to 2.4.1 or below. However, that is probably not a good idea, as there are [security disclosures](https://snyk.io/test/npm/socket.io/2.4.1) for socket.io 2.4.1 which can only be remediated by upgrading to >=3.0.0.

Alternatively, I would suggest just not using the `ot` package, as it has not been updated in 7 years, and its [repository](https://github.com/operational-transformation/ot.js) states that they are looking for maintainers for the project. There are alternative operational transformation libraries [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:operational%20transformation), and one of them may suit your needs. CodeMirror itself also appears to have a package for collaborative editing: https://codemirror.net/6/examples/collab/